# Angular - Unhandled Navigation Error after building

Tags: angular, build, angular2-routing

I have built a simple angular app with 2 routes through the following command:

```
ng build --aot --prod --base-href ./
```

Then i open the `index.html` file located in the `dist` folder and the app runs but the the routes don't work and i get the following warning on console:

[image]

Hope to have explained my question well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: while using ng serve is it working properly?

Comment: @ashishpal yes it works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Angular routing engine will force you to host your app in some server (e.g. [IIS](https://blog.angularindepth.com/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis-60a0897742e7), [NodeJS](https://blog.cloudboost.io/run-your-angular-app-on-nodejs-c89f1e99ddd3) etc.)

A simple angular app without routes can run without hosting it on a server.

From [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml):

> Angular apps are perfect candidates for serving with a simple static HTML server. You don't need a server-side engine to dynamically compose application pages because Angular does that on the client-side.
>
> **If the app uses the Angular router, you must configure the server** to return the application's host page (index.html) when asked for a file that it does not have.

Comment: Why? Could it be because of the routing system?

Comment: I think you are correct, this is because of the routing system. Check out this [link](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration)

Answer (score 15):

Angular routing works if you use hash routing and define your base href as follows in your index.html.

```
<base href="#">
```

Comment: This worked for me, I had already setup Angular routing at the beginning and didn't really want to revert anything.

Comment: my school server hosting wouldn't work, this works great as a standalone !

Comment: This seems like the best answer, and a most common use case.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I would get:

> Unhandled Navigation Error:              main.af3eff424835a3d5642f.js:1

Because my base url was set to https://

```
<base href="https://example.com" />
```

But I was loading the site over http://

```
http://example.com
```

Solution was to either use the https:// url OR change the base url to allow access via http.

Answer (score 4):

**app/module.ts:**

```
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';


@NgModule({
 ...
 ],
 providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }]
})
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

As [benshabatnoam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53916999/5541434) said, **Using Angular routing engine will force you to host your app in some server**.
Until deploying the App, only in a demo case, you can set `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })` and use **hash** for routing to avoid hosting your App in a server.